# Deny acess to file-shares (SMB)?

Tags: windows, security, network-shares, smb, security-policy

There are security policies like:

- Deny logon locally
- Deny logon on through Remote Desktop Services
- Deny access this computer from network

Is there any policy to **deny** specific users/groups to access a file-share? It means deny only file-access (SMB share), and nothing else. Hence, I wouldn't want to use any of above' *deny* policies. As far as share-level and NTFS permissions are concerned, I am pretty aware how to setup. I would like to deny particular user/group to access any share, even if `Everyone` is allowed to access the shared resource.

Comment: Edit your Samba config file and use "invalid users = denied_user @denied_group" for the share you have defined...

Comment: My bad. I read SMB and thought Samba lol...